# Haskell function patterns 'otherwise'

Tags: function, haskell, pattern-matching

Is there a way I can create a function with multiple definitions for different patterns including one that is executed when no of the other function's statements patterns are matched?

E.g.:

```
someFunc (pattern1) = def1
someFunc (pattern2) = def2
someFunc (<otherwise/all other possible values>) = def3
```

Or if this is not possible, how can it be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the wildcard match `_`:

```
isJust :: Maybe a -> Bool
-- Here we don't care about what's inside the `Just`
isJust (Just _) = True
-- Here we don't care what it is, it's not a `Just` so return `False`
isJust _ = False
```

For clarification, patterns are tried in the order you define them, so the above function is *not* equivalent to

```
isJust _ = False
isJust (Just _) = True
```

because the `_` pattern is matched first.  What the compiler is actually doing is turning this into a case statement internally, so the first function would be equivalent to

```
isJust x = case x of
    Just _ -> True
    _      -> False
```

and as we know from every other programming language that has ever existed, case statements are tried in order.

Comment: But what if both definitions are be eglible? Will it then automaticly use the first encountered definition that fits the input value? Because in your example a Just value as argument would fit the second definition with the wildcard too right?

Comment: Patterns are tried in the order you define them in.  So `isJust _ = False`; `isJust (Just _) = True` would _not_ be the same function.